# Install Play 2.4.4

Tags: playframework, play-json

How to install Play 2.4.4 framework on mac?

Answer (score 1):

This guide is quite well: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Installing

I work on mac and have any problem with this guide.

**UPDATE**

I see now,  in the guide for 2.4.x there is no "mac". Use the "unix" part:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Installing

Both of them, 2.5 and 2.4 looks similar in the install part. I worked with both and do not remember any special installment options.